# Validate format in Notepad++ using Regex

Tags: notepad++, regex, format, validation

I am attempting to validate the below format. I have hundreds of lines of this and I am looking to search for JUST the incorrect ones in Notepad ++.

Ex. PN1|1G5555|

I want to just make sure that the "1G5555|" is correct. So far I have this:

(PN)[1]\|[1-2][A-Z][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]\|

However this only looks for correct format. How do I search for incorrect format?

Comment: This is the only why I could get this to work consistently. Its a bit nontechnical, but it works. If anyone has a way of condensing this, please post. 

(PN)[1]\|[^1-2][A-Z]\d{4}\||(PN)[1]\|[1-2][^A-Z]....\||(PN)[1]\|[1-2][^A-Z]....\||(PN)[1]\|[1-2][A-Z][^0-9]...\||(PN)[1]\|[1-2][A-Z].[^0-9]..\||(PN)[1]\|[1-2][A-Z]..[^0-9].\||(PN)[1]\|[1-2][A-Z]...[^0-9]\||

Comment: Define "incorrect ones"